# How to instantiate an Observable of an array of objects before valuechanges?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I'm following the [Autocomplete Angular Material documentation](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) (v5 Setting separate control and display values), and I'm running into some problems getting my data loaded.

The problem I'm having is that the filteredOptions in my code doesn't get populated until after the user starts typing. I need the list to show up before the user starts typing. I believe this is because they are using valueChanges, but I'm not quite sure how to make this piece of code work for my case. I need this pipe and map functionality, but I need the list to be loaded before the user changes the value of the Mat Autocomplete, not after.

Code taken from documentation link that I have more or less mirrored in my own code:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```
filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.categoryList.slice())
      );
  }

  filter(name: string): User[] {
    return this.categoryList.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }
```

```
this.categoryList = Object.entries(data.category).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
```

I was thinking I should probably be using some sort of subscribe, but I can't figure out the syntax to use them with pipe and map.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the obsevable?

Comment: you shouldn't need to do a subscribe.  I looked over the link you sent, and there is a complete stackblitz for that example here https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvpvmdxpkbql?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts upon receiving focus, it displays the list.  With what you have shown us, I don't see anything obvious wrong.  But maybe you are missing something from the html side.  If you post your entire example, we can better see what might be causing it.

Comment: @EduardoVargas I believe it is done through the async pipe. I'll include the html code for that example as well.

Comment: @ccamac I updated the code. The only difference between the example and my code is the way they instantiate the 'options' array. My options array is the 'categoryList' array that is populated after an API call during ngOnInit.

Comment: @masu9 you are right that the subscribe is done via the async pipe.  As for your categoryList array, it appears to me that this could be the problem.  I can't tell via what you have posted at this time, but the array should be an empty array (i.e. []) to start and then in the api calls subscribe have it's values reassigned to what is returned.  If you do that, it should work exactly the same as the example.

Comment: @ccamac This sort of brings me back to my original question. I need my data to be populated in this filteredCategories variable, which is of type Observable<User[]>, but my categoryList is of type User[]. How do I instantiate the observable using my list of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it was as simple as this, but this answer helped resolve everything. All I had to do was move my code outside of ngOnInit. [how to show autocomplete options on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536382/how-to-show-autocomplete-options-on-focus)

My filteredOptions was not waiting for the API data to come through since I had put this inside ngOnInit. Once I moved it inside the subscribe of my api call, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all you need to do is `startWith` the form's value:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.myControl.value as string), // typing the control's value
        map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.categoryList.slice())
      );
  }
```

A note that using a class method inside of an operator is a bit of an anti-pattern. It's generally important to keep things pure when using the Observable pattern - especially with more complicated logic.

To fix that, you'd probably want to make your `categoryList` an Observable, and your `filter` a pure function (bring it outside of your component, and give it another param so you can pass in the `categoryList`).

```
function filter(name: string, categoryList: User[]): User[] {
  categoryList.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

Then you can do like so:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = combineLatest(
      this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myControl.value as string)),
      this.categoryList
    ).pipe(
      map(([searchTerm, categoryList]) =>
        searchTerm ? filter(searchTerm, categoryList) : [ ...categoryList ])
    );
  }
```

Comment: I was also trying to play with the startWith value, but I couldn't get that to work either. No matter what I put here it doesn't change anything, I think because it isn't triggered until the user starts typing. (valueChanges). Which brings me back to my original question, should I be using subscribe instead?

Comment: Your other suggestion involves changing my categoryList to an Observable. How would I assign the data I'm getting from my API to this Observable? I assume you mean the same type as filteredOptions. Observable<User[]>

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about what's going on. If you're using the httpClient, you can pipe it into your observable: `categoryList$ = this.http.get<User[]>('endpoint')`. Otherwise you can use `of` if the value is static or a `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` if you expect the value to change.

Comment: As mentioned above, the async pipe will subscribe to that observable for you. I'm not super familiar with the CDK auto-complete, so unsure if there's maybe something in the API that stops showing options on an empty input...? If you start typing and then erase all text do the options show?

Comment: If I start typing, then erase all text, then the options DO still show. Hmm yeah I guess the async pipe would have taken care of the observable... I'm really just doing a simple subscribe to my API call and then assigning the data to my categoryList as shown in my code above. Not sure what could be causing the data not to show up without the user typing :(

Comment: you can always just call `myControl.setValue('')` when the input field is first focused. Not the best solution, but that may solve things for ya